# struts2 dojo tag is displaying abovethe struts form tag why so?

Tags: struts2

I am trying to use struts2 dojo: autocompleter tag inside the struts2:form tag but the autocompleter tag is displaying out of the struts:form . Can't i use struts-dojo-tag inside the struts form tag ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it should work inside a struts form. do you have a custom theme?

Comment: yes , i do have custom theme ,where/what should i change to make the struts dojo:autocomplete work in the struts2 :form.